# obfuscate position of input fields

Tags: c#, jquery, obfuscation, spam, bots

I am outputting some html on screen, mostly input fields. I am looking obfuscate the position of input in the markup and reposition them when the page loads. I am doing this to prevent spam bots entering values on screen. If they are outputted randomly, it should help prevent this!

I am working with jquery in my c# web application.

Any tips of information on how I might achieve the above?

Comment: I wouldn't want to visit your site using a screen reader, or try to move from field to field using the Tab key...

Comment: Have you considered [CAPTCHA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAPTCHA)?

Comment: How about using a CAPTCHA for spam bot prevention?

Comment: I don't think changing position is going to do much for you - a bot doesn't really care about where the fields are - it will likely focus on input fields with standard naming conventions - "name", "email", "comments", etc. A better option might be to use non-standard names for the fields that matter, so that a bot can't recognize them for what they are. Then, include a few hidden fields using the standard names. Since a human user won't see these fields, if they are anything other than blank when the data gets to your server, you'll know you're likely dealing with a bot and can discard.

Comment: @Yardboy - yes I have done this and also wrote a jquery plugin to change the id of my input fields every 5 seconds. Just wanted some extra protection though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think your reasoning justifies doing this for your case because of the reasons mentioned in the comments.  However, assuming that you had good reason to do this (one example might be to mix up the order of quiz questions to make it harder to cheat on an online test), it is still an interesting problem.

Assume that you have a container with id="container" that has as children all elements that can be reordered with class="reorderable".  An example of this is would be:

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="reorderable">1</div>
    <div class="reorderable">2</div>
    <div class="reorderable">3</div>
    <div class="reorderable">4</div>
</div>
```

You can then re-add these elements in random order to the container element with the following JQuery code:

```
var reorderables = $('#container .reorderable');
var reorderablesLength = reorderables.size();

while(reorderables.size() > 0){
    var rand = Math.floor(Math.random()*reorderables.size())
    $('#container').append(reorderables.splice(rand, 1));
}
```

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/briguy37/xBdJn/) is a fiddle to test this.